# Select from same column (possible different row) in one select statement using JOINs

Tags: mysql, select, join, nested

First, I searched and found similar questions but none looks like what I need.

Second, I made a select statement that return what I want, but I'm not using JOINs, and I want, if possible, use JOINs, do it and understanding it with JOINs.

Let's say I have these tables (simplified, because actual tables are bigger):

```
products: 
fields: idproduct, name, idbaseunit; 
primary key: idproduct
foreign key: idbaseunit references units.idunit
-----------------------------------------------

units: 
fields: idunit, name
primary key: idunit
-----------------------------------------------

prodVSunit:
fields: idprodvsunit, idproduct, idunit, timesbaseunit, cost
primary key: idprodvsunit
foreign key: idproduct references products.idproduct
foreing key: idunit references units.idunit
-----------------------------------------------
```

The behavior of this is that I can have different units for the same product that are multiples of baseunit but the cost is not relative as the multiples are. My english is not that good, I don't know if this is well explained, so, here is an example:

If I register rice as a product and ounce as baseunit for it, I can have pound (= 16 ounces) as a unit. If I sell it ounce by ounce the price may be different from pounds selling, let's say $1.00 for an ounce, $15.45 for a pound.

In the database it looks like this:

```
insert into units(`idunit`, `name`) values(1,'ounce')
insert into units(`idunit`, `name`) values(2,'pound')

insert into products(`idproduct`, `name`, `idbaseunit`) values(1,'rice',1)
insert into products(`idproduct`, `name`, `idbaseunit`) values(2,'sugar',1)

insert into prodVSunit(`idprodvsunit`, `idproduct`, `idunit`, `timesbaseunit`, `cost`) values(1,1,1,1,1.00)
insert into prodVSunit(`idprodvsunit`, `idproduct`, `idunit`, `timesbaseunit`, `cost`) values(2,1,2,16,15.45)
insert into prodVSunit(`idprodvsunit`, `idproduct`, `idunit`, `timesbaseunit`, `cost`) values(3,2,1,1,0.85)
```

If I run this statement I get what I want:

```
select pro.name as product, un.name as unit, pvu.timesbaseunit as 'times base unit', 
aux.name as 'base unit', pvu.cost
from units un, prodVSunit pvu, products pro,
(select prod.idproduct, prod.idbaseunit, unt.name from products prod, units unt
where prod.idbaseunit = unt.idunit) as aux  
where aux.idproduct = pvu.idproduct and pvu.idproduct = pro.idproduct and pvu.idunit = un.idunit
```

The query returns:

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------
product______|unit______|times base unit_|base unit_____|cost_
-------------------------------------------------------------------
rice_________|ounce_____|1_______________|ounce_________|1_________
rice_________|pound_____|16______________|ounce_________|15.45_____
sugar________|ounce_____|1_______________|ounce_________|0.85______
```

Note that (in the result) 'unit' and 'base unit' are from same table column but sometime from different row.

So far so good, but I cannot figure it out using JOINs, is it possible??? the main reason that I want it with JOINs is that with 2 nested queries is fine and easy, but, if I have 7 or 8 relations like that, it is going to be a mess

Please, forgive me for the long post and Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to join to the units table twice.

I rewrote your query using ANSI joins to make it more readable, and then replaced the qub-query with a second join to units:

```
select pro.name as product, un.name as unit, pvu.timesbaseunit as 'times base unit', 
  baseUnit.name as 'base unit', pvu.cost
from prodVSunit pvu
  inner join units un on pvu.idunit = un.idunit
  inner join products pro on pvu.idproduct = pro.idproduct
  inner join units baseUnit on pro.idbaseunit = baseUnit.idunit
```